# Trying to run gulp

Tags: gulp, npm-install

I'm trying to install gulp in my windows 8 system. When I install `npm install -g`, it's working fine.

After that, when I install gulp in the required folder, it throws the errors of npm install. When I again install npm in the folder it also throws the errors.

[image: Gulp error]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Please edit your question to clarify what's already there, add additional details and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to install gulp in my windows 8 system. 

for gulp installation first I install npm after that I run the the command *npm install -g gulp*

after the when I check gulp version its showing fine. When I run the command gulp in the required folder it shown run the command npm install gulp then I run that command in the required folder after the installation. Again I run the command *gulp* then I met with above error